# VSTS tasks not linked to PBI's and tags not available after OpsHub migration

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

I've tried running the OpsHub migration tool to migrate TFS2013 on prem to VSTS. There's a couple of quirks I've managed to iron out, but the big two are:

- Tasks are unparented in VSTS, the link wasn't preserved?
- Tags aren't migrated

Has anyone else had this issue?

Comment: Can you verify your OVSMU version? Is 2.0.0.000?

Comment: @OpshubInc. Yes, that's the version I'm using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are sorry to inform you but in the .000 release of v2.0 of our tool, there was a regression in Links and Relationship.
Can you please install the latest patch release ie. 2.0.0.002 from the Gallery and re-do the migration.
Links between WIT is still a part of the Free Version of the utility. :)

And we plan to support the 'tags' very soon for VSTS.

Comment: I'll do that, thanks for your response! Do you know when tag support will be available?

Comment: Lol... too many complaints, so they added functionality back ;)

Answer (score 3):

I believe that OpsHub are now charging extra for "preserving links" both between work items and between code and work items. Additionally I would not be surprised if Tags were on that list as well.

You should switch to the TFS Integration Tools, which are free.

They are a lot more complicated, cumbersome, and buggy but they work... Although there is only an old release it works with VSTS.

Comment: That's shocking considering Microsoft recommend OpsHub and are pushing for VSTS. I'll take a look at that, thanks.

Comment: Looks like Team Explorer 2008/2010 is needed to run the TFS Integration Tools...?